# iOS Use of Undeclared Identifier in Class method for creating a new entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, class, core-data

I am trying to implement a simple factory method for creating a new entity for my core data database. In `Pet+Create.h`:

```
+ (Pet *)petWithName:(NSString *)name
          weight:(NSNumber *)weight
    weightIsInKg:(BOOL)yesorno
inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
```

In `Pet+Create.m`:

```
+ (Pet *)petWithName:(NSString *)name
          weight:(NSNumber *)weight
    weightIsInKg:(BOOL)yesorno
inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
Pet *newPet = nil;

newPet = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Pet" inManagedObjectContext:context];
newPet.name = name;
newPet.idealWeight = weight;
newPet.weightIsInKg = [NSNumber numberWithBool:weightIsInKg];

return newPet;
}
```

And finally, in `Pet.h`: (which is a generated file by xcode, I have not touched it)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Pet : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * idealWeight;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * weightIsInKg;

@end
```

My problem is, I am getting a `Use of undeclared identifier: weightIsInKg` error message on `newPet.weightIsInKg = [NSNumber numberWithBool:weightIsInKg];`
Why am I getting this error? I have obviously declared `weightIsInKg` because it is in the method name! Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter with which `petWithName` is called is named `yesorno`

```
weightIsInKg:(BOOL)yesorno
```

then you refer to it as `weightIsInKg`

```
newPet.weightIsInKg = [NSNumber numberWithBool:weightIsInKg];
```

Use instead

```
newPet.weightIsInKg = [NSNumber numberWithBool:yesorno];
```

Comment: Oh gosh. Can't believe I overlooked that. Just needed a fresh pair of eyes. +1!

Answer (score 0):

Your method argument is called `yesorno`, not `weightIsInKg`. Use `yesorno` or sanitize your variable names.